# INTO behavior difference in Rebol 2 parsing vs Rebol 3

Tags: parsing, rebol

Rebol's INTO allows the parser to descend into a series type (e.g. BLOCK! or PAREN!) to apply a match rule to the contents of the block.  Here's a simple example in Rebol 3:

```
data: [(a b)]

parse data [into [pos: 'a 'b (
    probe pos
    either pos = (first data) [
        print rejoin ["equal to original " mold first data]
    ] [
        print rejoin ["not equal to original " mold first data]
    ]
)]]
```

As the only thing in the block is a parenthesized series, the INTO rule is matched right away.  Using a SET-WORD!, the parser is told to capture the position upon entry to the parentheses in `pos`.  A and B are matched as literal LIT-WORD!s, and then the ensuing code is executed.  The expected result happens:

```
(a b)
equal to original (a b)
```

That's great.  But weirdly, Rebol 2 transforms parens into blocks for the same code:

```
[a b]
not equal to original (a b)
```

The same block conversion happens if your input is `data: [a/b]`:

```
[a b]
not equal to original a/b
```

Why does this happen?  Is there a way to get the Rebol 3 behavior if you're using Rebol 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a property Carl found "weird" in R2. Therefore, he replaced it in R3 by a more expectable behaviour. Curiously, the block you obtain that way is identical with the paren! (just try to change the contents), but declares it has a different type. However, if you need to refer to the paren in R2, your code can be easily adjusted:

```
data: [(a b)]

parse data [pos: into ['a 'b (
    pos: first pos
    probe pos
    either pos = (first data) [
        print rejoin ["equal to original " mold first data]
    ] [
        print rejoin ["not equal to original " mold first data]
    ]
)]]
```

another modification that gives you the desired result:

```
data: [(a b)]
parse data [set pos into ['a 'b] (
    probe pos
    either pos = (first data) [
        print rejoin ["equal to original " mold first data]
    ] [
        print rejoin ["not equal to original " mold first data]
    ]
)]
```

Comment: Ah, interesting - I had not tested to see that they were actually "aliased" instances of the same information, but did not compare as equal.  *(I've only seen that happen one other place with AS-BINARY and AS-STRING in R2.)*

Comment: Yes, `as-binary`, `as-string` and `disarm` exhibit this behaviour as well.